# Using an int to get an element from an array doesn't work

Tags: c#

This line of code doesn't work as intended.

```cs
artworkImage.sprite = defaultCard.artwork[defaultCard.selectedArtworkNumber];
```

I've used `Debug.Log` to find out that `selectedArtworkNumber` does indeed change. And it's an integer too, so there should be nothing wrong there. It's just that line that doesn't work.

It does work if I input a compiler constant value, like `0`, though.
There aren't any errors in the console either.

Comment: Consider putting together a [mcve].

Comment: Many times I've seen a developer say "I'm right, and c# is wrong; this code should do x and it doesn't", but I don't recall the assertion ever turning out to be true. Show us a screenshot of the debugger paused just after this line, and make sure the locals window is visible and all variables mentioned on the line are showing within it

Comment: If it doesn't work as intended, what exactly does it do?

Comment: if `defaultCard.selectedArtworkNumber` does in fact change, then what value is it changing to? Once you know that value, since `artwork` is an array, my next question would be what is the count of items in the `artwork` array? Does the value in `defaultCard.selectedArtworkNumber` indicate a valid index within the `artwork` array? If it does map to a valid index within the `artwork` array, is the item at that index specified by `defaultCard.selectedArtworkNumber` contain a valid value for the `sprite` property?

Comment: @The-Anonymous What the code does is it first in a seperate script gets a sprite array, turns that array into a list, adds that list to a dropdown, uses dropdown.value to get the index number of the selected value when the dropdown value is changed and then sets that to a variable (int) the other scripts have access to. Then the script that i took the line of code from basically says the sprite of this image object should be from the artwork array and should be number <the int that stores the index number of the selected dropdown option> as the dropdown index number also starts from 0

Comment: Maybe defaultCard.selectedArtworkNumber is a nullable int ?

Comment: @carl6005 What's the length of `defaultCard.artwork` and what's the value of `selectedArtworkNumber`?

Comment: @The-Anonymous The length of the artwork array is 3 (With that i mean 0 to 2). The value of selectedArtworkNumber changes depending on which item i pick in the dropdown. The maximum is 2 and the minimum is 0. I have confirmed that this works by putting an Debug.Log(selectedArtworkNumber) in update and it does update to valid numbers (between 0 and 2) depending on the dropdown option i pick.

Comment: @quaabaam It changes between 0, 1 and 2. The length of the artwork array is also 3. And yes it does. It'd be impossible for it not to as i make the array into a list, put that list into a dropdown and use the dropdown.value property to get the index of the selected option every time the selected option changes. The index value of dropdowns also count from 0. And all three indexes have a sprite that i defined in the inspector.